# Redirect unauthenticated user to different page via ajax/jQuery $.post

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

I have a jQuery post call like the following:

```
$.post('/Controller/_PartialAction', { 'param1': data }, function(result) { });
```

That's fine and it all works, except when a user's authentication cookie expires.

What happens is, there is already stuff in there that will redirect `/Controller/_PartialAction` to the login page, BUT the partial action in this case is a partial view, instead I want to redirect a full view.

So it is already redirecting that to the login page, but I want to redirect a different page, say I want to redirect to `/Controller/Index`. Is there any way to specify an error path or redirect path in an ajax/jQuery call?

I.E., something like this (This doesn't exist, but like what i'm trying to do)

```
$.post({success}, {redirect}, {error}, {data}, {function})
```

So basically, how can I do a jQuery/ajax post call with a different url for errors so I can redirect to that one?

*edit*

What is being redirected is the ajax call itself. So I can't redirect it from the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're after, but (based on http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) could you use the underlying $.ajax (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and set an `error` function?

Or can you test for the expiration of the cookie in the success callback, then redirect based on the result of that test.

Comment: I ultimately came up with something like this.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to define the action URL based on whether a user's sessions has expired?

Why don't you define the action URL as a variable and then use it in the post call:

```
// Use an asp.net function to work out whether session has expired
if( ... ) {
   // Session expired
   var url = 'Controller/Index';
} else {
   // Session alive
   var url = 'Controller/_PartialAction';
}

$.post(url, { 'param1': data }, function(result) { });
```